# Bootstrap 4 - row destryoing layout - Why row-fluid needing? Diifference between row and row-fluid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 background-color: #0d0d0d !important;
}
body a {
 color: #fff;
}
body a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
 .container{
  width: 1470px !important;
 }
}
nav {
 background: #1c1c1c !important;
 color: #ccc !important;
}
.toper {
 padding: 100px;
 background: #071931;
 color: #fff;
}
.main {
 background: #121212;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-top: -60px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px 15px;
}
.container-first {
 background: #2a2a2a;
 margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
 padding: 5px;
}
.breadcrumb {
 margin: 0px;
 background: #2a2a2a;
}
.social img
{
 margin-right: 15px;
 padding: 2px;
 background: #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .social img {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
.welcome {
 background: #444;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0px !important;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.margin-bottom-small
{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.margin-bottom-small::before
{
 content: '';
 display: table;
}
.welcome-header
{
 padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
 background: #2d2d2d;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}
.welcome-text
{
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #ccc;
}
.welcome-action {
 padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
 background: #4d4d4d;
 color: #ccc;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.bluer {
 padding: 15px;
 background: #046092;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-weight: 500;
}
.section-bluer
{
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.section-container
{
 padding: 0px;
}
.section-first
{
 background: #1c1c1c;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.section-picture
{
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.section-picture > img
{
 border: 1px solid #016d9b;
}
.section-this p
{
 color: #ccc;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.section-this h4 a
{
 color: #87b8d7;
 font-weight: 500;
}
.section-this hr
{
 border: none;
 border-top: 1px dotted #444;
}
.section-count {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.small-text {
 font-size: 10px;
}
.section-last-post
{
 padding: 0px;
}
.zero-padding
{
 padding: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
{
 .last-topic-img
 {
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .section-count
 {
  padding: 0px;
 }
}
.last-topic p
{
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.abox
{
 background: #282828;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #282828;
 padding: 5px;
 padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.popular-autors p
{
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    
    <main class="container main">
   <div class="container-fluid container-first row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
     <nav class="breadcrumb">
       <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Home</a>
       <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Library</a>
       <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Data</a>
       <span class="breadcrumb-item active">Bootstrap</span>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 my-auto">
     <div class="float-lg-right text-center social">
      <a href="#"><img src="fb.png" /></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="tw.png" /></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="g.png" /></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid welcome">
    <div class="margin-bottom-small"></div>
    <header class="welcome-header">
     Witaj eeeeeeeeeeeee  | Kody, Porady | Gry online
    </header>
    <div class="welcome-text">
     <small>Zarejestruj się, aby otrzymać dostęp do wszystkich funkcjonalności forum.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-action">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Zaloguj się</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Zarejestruj się</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid bluer">
    <a href="#">Najnowszy news: #98 Tygodnik yyyyyNews - O grach MMORPG słów kilka!</a>
   </div>

   <div clas="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-9 zero-padding">
      <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////KONIEC 1 kategori -->
       <div class="row section-bluer">
        <div class="bluer">
         Projektyyyyyyyyyy
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid section-container">
         <div class="row section-first">
          <div class="col-lg-1 section-picture my-auto">
           <img src="fb.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 section-this my-auto">
           <h4><a href="#">League of Legends</a></h4>
           <p>Ćwicz swój refleks, opanuj percepcję i zostań przywódcą grupy! Stań się prawdziwym bohaterem świata League of Legends i doskonal swoje umiejętności taktyczne.</p>
           <hr>
           <a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a><a href="#">Metin2 - Publikacje Serwerów, </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1 section-count text-center my-auto small-text">
           <b>230683</b> tematy
           <b>1246366</b> odpowiedzi
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 section-last-post my-auto">
           <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-4 my-auto last-topic-img text-center">
              <img src="fb.png" />
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-8 small-text last-topic my-auto text-center">
              <p><a href="#">Przerwa techniczna 09-05-2…</a></p>
              <p><a href="#">Przez Krystian</a></p>
              <p>9 maj</p>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////KONIEC 1 kategori -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 zero-padding">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid abox">
        Reklama
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row abox">
        Popularni Autorzy
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
     <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Początek autora popularnego -->
      <div class="row text-center popular-autors" >
       <div class="col-xl-1 my-auto">
        <p>1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 my-auto">
        <a href="#"><img src="fb.png" /></a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-9 my-auto">
        <a href="#"><p>Misiegg</p></a>
        <p><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> 54</span></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////KONIEC autora popularnego -->
     </div>
     <div class="row abox">
       Ostatnie Posty
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
```

As you can see it's:

[image]

And it it looks good after I change `<div class="row section-bluer">` to `<div class="row-fluid section-bluer">`

Why is there row-fluid needed?

And

[image]

Why there is free space from left side? I can't fix it no matter what I try to do.

And generally what is the difference between row and row-fluid?

I look for this in documentation `https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/`, every page, and there is absolutely no information about this.

And everywhere in code in bootstrap 4 documentation is used `row`, never `row-fluid` Why?

Why in my example I need row-fluid? What is difference in general between these two?

Comment: There is no `row-fluid` in Bootstrap 4. Do you mean `container-fluid`? Create a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: There is. I typed the problem in this question. this is a big example

Comment: @ZimSystem `<div class="row section-bluer">` to `<div class="row-fluid section-bluer">` And works..... eh

Comment: No, `.row-fluid` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4, it's just your code is being impacted by the removal of the `.row` class which creates a negative margin. You could replace `.row` with foobar and still get the same effect since **row-fluid is doing nothing and doesn't exist**.

Comment: I see @ZimSystem. So why then .row is destryoing my whole main layout. As I used it properly... I think, or not?

Comment: There are various issues that could be fixed by cleaning up the code. For example, your missing a closing `</div>` tag. There shouldn't be so many containers. `col-*` should be wrapped in `.row`, and ***only* `col-*` should be the immediate child of `.row`**. .row should be wrapped in a single `container` or `container-fluid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many nested `container`/`container-fluid`. You only need 1 outer container, and nested columns should always be placed directly in `.row`.

Pseudo code...

```
   container
       row
         col-*
            row 
              col-*
              col-*
            /row
         /col
       /row
   /container
```

Comment: I did many containers because on w3 `Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding` . especially `row must be` so before every row i placed this